# Scheme function that return average odds

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to create a scheme function that will return the average of the odd number in list. For example

```
(avg-odd 4 5 5 5 5 5)
```

would return 5. This is what I have so far

```
(define avg-odd
  (lambda vals
    (if (odd? x)
        (/(apply + vals) (length vals)))))
```

When running it says missing else expression. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried adding your else expression to match the if?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of [if](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=if#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._if%29%29) is *(if test-expr then-expr else-expr)*, so all expressions have to look like this:
`(if (odd? 5) "odd" "even")`.
In your example, you are missing *else-expr* part. If you need condition without *else-expr*, use [when](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/when_unless.html?q=when#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._when%29%29), which can have this form:
`(when (odd? 5) "odd")`.
Actually, none of them is needed here. You need to filter all odd numbers and then count average. You can use built-in function [filter](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=filter#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29):

```
(define avg-odd (lambda vals
                  (let ((odd-vals (filter odd? vals)))
                    (if (null? odd-vals) 0
                        (/ (apply + odd-vals)
                           (length odd-vals))))))

(avg-odd 4 5 5 5 5 5)
```

or write your own function for filtering:

```
(define filter-odd (lambda (lst)
                       (cond ((null? lst) lst)
                             ((odd? (car lst)) (cons (car lst)
                                                     (filter-odd (cdr lst))))
                             (else (filter-odd (cdr lst))))))

(define avg-odd (lambda vals
                  (let ((odd-vals (filter-odd vals)))
                    (if (null? odd-vals) 0
                        (/ (apply + odd-vals)
                           (length odd-vals))))))

(avg-odd 4 5 5 5 5 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

An `if` needs a "true" branch and a "false" branch, and you only have a "true" branch.
There is also no `x` that you can pass to `odd?`, and `(/(apply + vals) (length vals))` is the average of the entire list.

The point of this exercise is to train you to think "I wrote a function to calculate the average of a list yesterday, so if I had a list of only the odd numbers, I could use that function and do less work today".

If you have encountered `filter`, that's what you should use:

```
(define (avg-odd ls) (avg (filter odd? ls)))
```